# Selecting default value of a column from empty table (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql that is currently empty. One of the column is `timestamp`,  which is set to have a default value( a fixed value and not current timestamp).

Now currently I don't have any rows, but I want to fetch the default timestamp from timestamp column. I have tried something, but it's not working.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DEFAULT(`timestamp`) FROM `mytable`");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$time = $row['timestamp'];

echo $time;
```

I don't know how to get that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you select current timestamp from mysql? try `<?=time()?>`

Comment: I just edited my question a bit.. The default timestamp is not the current timestamp.. It's just a fixed timestamp... I want to fetch that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table 'mytable' has a field called 'timestamp' and you need this default value , this is the approach:

```
$sql = mysql_query("EXPLAIN `mytable`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  if ($row['Field'] == 'timestamp') {
     echo $row['Default'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL since version 5.02 has a 'data dictionary' that can be queried with select statements.

```
SELECT column_default FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'your_table'
AND column_name = 'your_column'
```

returns the appropriate information.

a google search for 'mysql information_schema' returns lots of references. I am not sure if it is ok to post http links in here.

Answer (score 0):

your code looks correct, only the key in your array access seems to be wrong.
tjis should work:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT  DEFAULT(`timestamp`) AS default_timestamp FROM `mytable`");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$time = $row['default_timestamp'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("DESCRIBE `mytable`");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    if ($result['Field'] == 'timestamp') {
        $default = $result['Default'];
        break;
   }
}

echo $default;
```

Cheers